# Show/hide menu in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to show and hide the menu when i click the menu-button. Don't really know how to get forward with this? I want to write it with Vue 3.

```js
const openMenu = () => {
    showMenuContent: {
        type: Boolean
        required: true,
        default: false,
    }
}
```

```html
<a class="" @click="openMenu()">Menu</a>

        <div v-if="showMenuContent(true)">Menu-div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a reactive variable to toggle the menu on/off

example using `script setup`

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
const isOpen = ref(false)
```

template

```
<button @click="isOpen = !isOpen">Menu</button>

<div v-if="isOpen">Menu-div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I also have a close button in the menu-div, so when I press it I want to close the menu-div, how can I do that? I am using you toogle example now but I need a @click="closeMenuDiv". But I dont know how to do it..?

Comment: its the same concept :
when ever you need to close the menu you assaign the isOpen variable to false.
`<div @click="isOpen = false">from inside the menu</div>`